# HMAC md5 encryption/decryption in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, hash, hmac

I have the php code for making HMAC md5 encryption

```
$input = 'foo';
$output = hash_hmac('md5', $input, $secretKey);
```

After making the hash,is there anyway I could get the $input back to text form.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between encryption (which MD5 is **not**) and hashing is that hashing is unidirectional. The answer is no.

Comment: So why actually hashing is used?And why does key is used?

Comment: @user3637105 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Applications